# How to export Plotly figure to PDF without Kaleido?

Tags: python, html, pdf, plotly

Is there any way, other than Kaleido, to export a Plotly figure to a PDF? I'm on a Windows computer and Kaleido isn't working for me (hanging on export), and it seems the package isn't being worked on anymore. I can export to html just fine though, but I need a PDF to be the final product.

I've tried exporting the html to a PDF, but I can only use packages through PyPi, nothing external, which I think is why that route didn't work either.

Example code:

```
import plotly.express as px

data_canada = px.data.gapminder().query("country == 'Canada'")
fig = px.bar(data_canada, x='year', y='pop')
fig.show()

plotly.io.write_image(fig, "fig.pdf", format="pdf", engine="kaleido")
```

Comment: You presumably can export a figure to an image format (PNG etc.) - hopefully also to a memory object (`bytes`). If that is the case, then use PyMuPDF to open an empty PDF via `doc = fitz.open()`, give it an empty page `page = doc.new_page(width=w, height=h)` and then insert the image binary as a full page picture: `page.insert_image(page.rect, stream=stream)`.